# How do I use indexOf to get the index of a selected NSCollectionView?

Tags: macos, swift, indexing, xcode7, nscollectionview

I've seen some examples in Objective-C such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805887/getting-model-from-click-on-nscollectionview-item), but `NSCollectionView.subview` uses a property called `.indexOfObject` which I am assuming has been replaced with `.indexOf`, but I'm not sure how to use `.indexOf`.

**Context in Objective-C**

```
NSInteger index = [[myCollectionView subviews]  indexOfObject:self];
```

**Swift Version**

```
var index = collectionView.subviews.indexOf(element: Self.Generator.Element)
```

**Question:**

How do I use `indexOf` to get the index of a selected `NSCollectionView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `indexOf` is straightforward:

```
let label = UILabel()
let tableView = UITableView()

let subviews: [UIView] = [label, tableView]

print(subviews.indexOf(label))     // Optional(0)
print(subviews.indexOf(tableView)) // Optional(1)
```

As you can see, it returns an optional which will be `nil` if the object is not found in the array. You can unwrap the actual index like this

```
if let index = collectionView.subviews.indexOf(self) {
    // do your stuff
} else {
    // view not found in subviews
}
```

Comment: Does the same apply to OS X NSCollectionView?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu If the Objective-C code in the question that you linked works, then yes. The method `indexOf` belongs to the `CollectionType` protocol and is independent of `NSCollectionView`.